# MySQL join table based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirement where If a certain conditions matches then I need to apply JOIN otherwise, I don't need to apply it.

for example

A,B and C are tables

so I need to join B and C if the B.id not in (select entityId from A) otherwise there will be no join.

also here A and C don't have common values.

```
Table A

    id entityId name
    1  xyz        abc
    2  bcd        z
    3  edc        x
    
    Table B
    id entityId shopRegID
    1  bcd       z
    
    Table C
    id entityId newEntityID ShopNewname
    1  xyz       xyze        abcd
    2  e          ee          sd
```

now I have condition like this, where I need to get the data from these table ,based on the entityId provided to me.
I need to eliminate all the shops which are not registered(not in table B) but include the shops which are renamed(in table C but not in B)

suppose If I am given ('xyz','bcd','edc')
the output should contains
bcd       (because it's in table B)
xyz       (because it's in table C)

and these table have very large amount of data(in 100 thousands )

what is the best and performant way to achive this.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What columns are being selected?  You can't be selecting columns from the joined tables if this all fits into one query.  What does "no join" mean?  A Cartesian product?

Comment: A few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: @GordonLinoff have added the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `left join` and `coalesce` as follows:

```
select * 
  from tableA A
  left join tableB B on a.entityid  = b.entityid
  left join tableB C on a.entityid  = c.entityid
 WHERE coalesce(b.entityid,c.entityid) is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want entities from `a` that are in either of the tables.  This suggests `exists` logic:

```
select a.*
from a
where exists (select 1 from b where b.entityId = a.entityId) or
      exists (select 1 from c where c.entityId = a.entityId)
```